# How can we create an onclick event for a d3 data map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a d3 data map:
http://datamaps.github.io/

When I click on a country, I want the border to change color. How do I assign an onclick event to a d3 path using datamaps? The svg paths seem to lack a CSS ID as well as any identifying hook.

Comment: If you're using that github project, it might be better to submit an issue to add a "highlight on click" option. There's already highlight on hover so you could fork the project and add a mousedown event here https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/public/js/app/views/Map.js#L88

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery "done:function" and specify on("click") as below :

```
 done: function(datamap) {
        datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
            alert(geography.properties.name);
        });
    }
```

Refer to https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps for further detail.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need both the `done` call back as well as the `updateChoropleth` function. For example, to turn each country black you would do:

```
done: function(datamap) {
  datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
      var m = {};
      m[geography.id] = '#000000';
      datamap.updateChoropleth(m);
  });
}
```